# Perform two joins on each row of a table individually?

Tags: mysql, database

I am building part of a website that manages user attendance.

There are four tables involved: user, attendance (the many-to-many link) and event.

The attendance table simply stores the userId and eventId and whether they were present, absent, sick or on leave.

I am trying to create a mySQL query that will show each user-event pair that does not have an attendance record ie. they have not been marked as present, sick etc.

I have tried using an INNER JOIN from user to attendance and then a RIGHT JOIN from attendance to event but this would have to be performed individually for each user. I'm not sure if I'm heading in the right direction or sure how to make the query iterate within SQL.

Thanks in advance!

More Info:

**User Table**

`+-----+---------+
| id  |  name   |
+-----+---------+
| 104 | Matthew |
| 102 | Kev     |
| 101 | Julia   |
+-----+---------+`

**Attendance**

`+----+--------+---------+------+
| id | userId | eventId | type |
+----+--------+---------+------+
| 16 |    104 |      47 | L    |
| 20 |    104 |      46 | L    |
| 21 |    104 |      45 | L    |
| 22 |    102 |      47 | L    |
| 23 |    102 |      46 | L    |
| 24 |    102 |      45 | L    |
| 28 |    102 |      44 | L    |
| 25 |    101 |      47 | L    |
| 26 |    101 |      46 | L    |
| 27 |    101 |      45 | L    |
+----+--------+---------+------+`

**Events**

`+----+------------+
| id |    date    |
+----+------------+
| 43 | 2014-08-01 |
| 44 | 2014-08-08 |
| 45 | 2014-08-15 |
| 46 | 2014-08-22 |
| 47 | 2014-08-29 |
+----+------------+`

**My attempt:**

```
SELECT * FROM `user` 
INNER JOIN attendance ON user.id=userId 
RIGHT JOIN event ON attendance.eventId=event.id 
WHERE event.date BETWEEN '2014-08-01' AND CURDATE()
```

**Goal**

Ideally I would like a table returned with the userId and event Id of records that don't exist.

`+--------+---------+
| userId | eventId |
+--------+---------+
|    104 |      43 |
|    104 |      44 |
|    102 |      43 |
|    101 |      43 |
|    101 |      44 |
+--------+---------+`

Comment: Post your attempts, the table structure etc. so we know what you're working with

Comment: Does that help a bit?

Comment: Much better, cheers :)

Comment: event id '81` ah how? your sample data doesn't have 81

Comment: I want to be able to see all the instances where a user isn't linked to a parade so that I can make the link with the correct 'type' value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to get my head around this. I'm not so hot on MySQL so I expect this answer can be improved upon but fundamentally what you need to do is get the users and events that are NOT in the attendance table:

**Query:**

```
SELECT u.id as 'userID', e.id as 'eventID'
FROM event e
JOIN user u
WHERE e.id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT event.id FROM event
    INNER JOIN attendance ON attendance.eventId=event.id 
    WHERE attendance.userId=u.id AND event.date BETWEEN '2014-08-01' AND CURDATE()
)
AND e.date BETWEEN '2014-08-01' AND CURDATE() 
ORDER BY u.id DESC;
```

**Result:**

```
+--------+---------+
| userID | eventID |
+--------+---------+
|    104 |      43 |
|    104 |      44 |
|    102 |      43 |
|    101 |      43 |
|    101 |      44 |
+--------+---------+
```

**Demo SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82dd9f/19/0

Comment: Thank you! I knew what I needed but was to focused on joins :D

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT a.*,b.type FROM user a right JOIN attendance b ON a.userId =b.userId  WHERE a.userId=<your Value> and b.in eventId in (select event Id from Events where event.date BETWEEN '2014-08-01' AND CURDATE())
```